# how to return only few values of a list rather than returning all the values

Tags: django

I have a django list as below: the **hotess1** is a database result set.

```
for hotel in hotels1:
            if models.CalendarDay.objects.filter(hotel=hotel, date=date).count() == 0:
                similar_venues.append(hotel)
```

The list size is dynamic but i want to return only first three values

I can do as below:

```
for hotel in hotels:
        if models.CalendarDay.objects.filter(hotel=hotel, date=date).count() == 0:
            similar_venues.append(hotel)
            counter += 1
            if counter == 3: break
```

but i want to do it in a better way.. any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the slice operator: `my_list[:3]` will return a list containg the first three values of `my_list`.

(unless there are less than three values, in which case you get everything back).